# Does the overflow hidden technique to solve container collapse work only for section tag?

Tags: html, css

Does the `overflow: hidden` technique to solve container collapse problem work only for section tag?

```
<style>
aside, article, section, header, footer, nav {
    display: block;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background: rgb(108,135,178);
}
body {
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font: 90% Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
}
section {
    background: rgb(178,155,107);
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 580px;
}
.one {
    background: rgb(207, 255, 245);
    float: left; 
}
.two {
    background: rgb(101,209,255);
    float: left;
}
.three {
    background: rgb(255, 231, 181);
    float: left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="three">Three</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

see this example 
I use overflow: hidden here it solves the container collapse problem

but what happens when I change it like this

```
<style>
aside, article, section, header, footer, nav {
    display: block;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    background: rgb(108,135,178);
}
body {
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font: 90% Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 50px;
}

.containerElement {
    background: rgb(178,155,107);
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 580px;
}
.one {
    background: rgb(207, 255, 245);
    float: left; 
}
.two {
    background: rgb(101,209,255);
    float: left;
}
.three {
    background: rgb(255, 231, 181);
    float: left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="containerElement">
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="three">Three</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The overflowing part is now hidden. This is how `overflow: hidden` is supposed to work. How come the `overflow: hidden` technique in section tag works like that?

Comment: Not sure we understand your question...

Comment: you know container collapse? then overflow:hidden solves that problem, but for some reason when I use it with section tag it works BUT didnt work with my div tag

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `containerElement` is a div, so the style rules for `div` are being used, and are then being overwritten by `containerElement`.

The `div` style rules specify `height: 50px;`, so the container is being set to a static height of 50px.

As a general rule of thumb, using CSS to style the `div` tag will cause you lots of problems.  If you change `div` to `.one, .two, .three`, you will get the result you want.

Comment: what do you mean by "If you change div to .one, .two, .three, you will get the result you want".

Comment: also what is the default height for section tag

Comment: The default height is just the height of whatever is in the content of the tag, and I mean change your CSS rule from `div { width: 50px; ... }` to `.one, .two, .three { width 50px; ... }`

Comment: Sorry i have hard time understanding english but i can understand some. For what i understand you mean default by saying "The div style rules specify height: 50px;"

Comment: and what is the reason to change the width in .one .two .three

Comment: *The div style rules specify height: 50px;* ... yes!
*and what is the reason to change the width in .one .two .three* ... you tell me, this is what **you** had in **your** code!  Why did **YOU** change the width?

Comment: damn sorry now I understand HAHAH sorry for wasting your time